# ios webview set status bar background to white and font color to black

Tags: ios, webview

building my first IOS app (new to IOS).my app is only a webview. how do i change the transparent background of the status bar to be always white and the text to be black?

my app support IOS 11 and later.
i am using Xcode 11 ,swift 5.[transparent status bar prblem screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gBywE.png)

Comment: i did, the status bar background still transparent.
`override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle{
        if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
            return .darkContent
        } else {
            // Fallback on earlier versions
            return .default
        }
    }`

Comment: Maybe this link will help you achieve desire result:-https://freakycoder.com/ios-notes-13-how-to-change-status-bar-color-1431c185e845

Comment: @MShaha  , where do i add this code? in which file and in which function? is it in the AppDelegate.swift? in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions?

Comment: @N.Sam in In ViewController file which you are using for webview.

Comment: In same class where web view is declared

Comment: @MShah ,@Muhammad Hasan. thank you very much! it solved the problem.